# Changing printer settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So I have the code below and when the dialog opens, it shows the printer settings have change to print double sided but when i click ok and prints, it does not prints double sided but but when i manually select double sided it does print correctly. any ideas what might be the case? Thanks in advance for your help. ASP.NET WEB Application

```
            using (PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog())
            {

                PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
                ps.Duplex = Duplex.Horizontal;
                pd.PrinterSettings = ps;
               // pd.UseEXDialog = true;



                if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
                    info.Verb = "Print";
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    Process.Start(info);
                }





            }
```

Comment: Just for confirmation is it  a web application. If this is a web application I am not sure if you can set the printer settings. because your code runs on server but client system is somewhere else. So overwriting client preference might not be possible. But I am not sure about this. There might be some way.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this checking `PrinterSettings.CanDuplex` Property. Just set

```
PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
```

and check if your printer supports it.

- This property gets a value indicating whether the printer supports double-sided printing.
- It returns `true` if the printer supports double-sided printing; otherwise, `false`.

You could simply do it like this:

```
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument MyPrintDocument = new PrintDocument();
        MyPrintDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPageEvent);
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages;
        MyPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages;
        MyPrintDocument.Print();
```

where `PrintPageEvent` is the event triggered on `Print()`;